# .NET: Return a list of strings given a list of whole words to match

Tags: c#, regex, string, match, string-matching

I need to split a string into substrings by a set of whole words.

Input:
`word wo wordword`

**Output (split by `word`):**

str1: `word`

str2: `[space]wo wordword`

**Output (split by `wo`):**

str1: `word[space]`

str2: `wo`

str3: `[space]wordword`

The method signature for the desired method should look like this:

```
public List<string> GetPhrases(string text, List<string> splitters);
```

Considerations:

- whole word matches only
- whitespaces should be preserved
- splitters list contains distinct words only
- a splitter does not contain whitespace
- matches should be case insensitive

With this method, I'll be able to highlight whole word matches in a UI window with the ability to match multiple words with different highlights, but I can't wrap my head around using regex.

Currently, I have a non-regex solution, but it's not great:

```
var words = Regex.Split(text, @"\s+").Where(s => s != string.Empty).ToList();
var str = "";
var list = new List<string>();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (!splitters.Contains(word))
    {
        if(words.IndexOf(word) != words.Count - 1)
            str += word + " ";
        else
            str += word;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(str))
           list.Add(str);

        list.Add(word);
        str = "";
    }
}

if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(str))
   list.Add(str);
```

The problem is I'm not maintaining any whitespace like newlines and instead replacing them with a space.

Comment: This is a statement of intent, not a problem. Also specify whether you want this case sensitive. And any code you have tried with a testable example

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service, and a list of requirements is not a question. Where exactly are you stuck, what is your actual programming-related question? With a reputation > 1000 points, i would have expected that you are aware of this...

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm sorry if this sounded like an intent. I did try many things, but I did not want to post complicated code to confuse people. I don't care for case sensitivity.

Comment: Quite to the contrary, it helps us copy the code, test and tweak. especially input lists and expected results

Comment: @MichaelRandall I provided a sample input and output list already at the beginning of the question. I'll add more. It's basically splitting the text based on exact whole word matches without case sensitivity.

Comment: If you can't do RegEx, do you have at least a non-regex solution? i.e. it should be not too hard to write a method that walks a string in a loop and splits it into chunks delineated by a particular word, then returns those chunks in an array.

Comment: @RufusL I have a non-regex incomplete solution and will post it in a bit.

Comment: @RufusL see my edit

Comment: `Regex.Split(s, $@"\b({string.Join("|", splitters)})\b").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`? Or, if the words are only chunks of non-whitespace, `Regex.Split(s, $@"(?<!\S)({string.Join("|", splitters.Select(Regex.Escape))})(?!\S)").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tested your first one several times, and it's working great. Would love to accept it as an answer. Needs to be case insensitive though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your splitter words are just streaks of alphanumeric or underscore chars, you may use

```
var results = Regex.Split(s, $@"\b({string.Join("|", splitters)})\b")
                   .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

Here, `\b(word1|word2)\b` pattern will match splitter words as whole words, and `Regex.Split` will split the string into the matching and non-matching chunks because of the capturing group (`(...)`) around the splitter words in the pattern.

The `.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))` will filter out empty strings that usually appear when the match happens be a consecutive match or at the start/end of the string.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28word%7Canother%29%5Cb&i=word%20wo%20wordword):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In your example, does it make a difference if we used `.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))` instead of null or empty? The splitter words are currently written in such a way that for each character `IsLetterOrDigit(Char)` must return true except for the first character as it's either @ or #.

Comment: @user246392 If you need a non-descrutive split, use `IsNullOrEmpty`, if you want to lose whitespace only chunks use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. The rest is unclear to me. Mentions and hashtags can be avoided if you use `(?<![@#])` lookbehind after the first `\b`.